# How to create a fade in action?

Tags: animation, materials, animation-nodes, nla-editor, actions

I have seen many videos that explain how to fade in an object and the corresponding keyframes are visible in the timeline. However, I have not been able to create an action with these keyframes (possibly because only material properties are changed an this not considered an action?). How can I get an action that fades in my object?

I currently use the NLA editor to combine all of my actions in the correct order and to have this order easily changed later on without ever baking a new animation. Is there a tool better suited for this purpose than the NLA editor?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Yes you can't create a node action but you can push the keyframes into the NLA though., open the NLA and unfold the track until you see the push down button

Comment: Thank you so much, this was very helpful!

Comment: Can you please give an example of the kind of fade-in animation you want to create? Screenshots of your current animation setup (Dope sheet / Action Editor, Nonlinear Animation editor) may also help.

Comment: It all looked very similar to the sceenshots in moonboot's accepted answer (except that there are many other tracks and strips in my NLA editor). I assume this thread will be helpful for others in its current state, but I can add more screenshots if you consider this helpful for others in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create a shader node action but you can push the keyframes into the NLA though, open the *NLA* and unfold the track until you see the push down button:

[image]

Now you have a strip that you can move, repeat, etc:

[image]